# jquery in html injection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example I have 2 input's and one button with attribute, where i wanna use input values, it may be something like this:

`<input data-link="test?input1=$('#input1'.val())&input2=$('input2.val()')" />`

Comment: Not possible. Maybe if you are going to tell us what you want to do with `data-link`, we can propose an alternative solution.

Comment: You can't use jQuery like PHP just because of the `$`

Comment: i didn't get what you're trying to do, when you're pressing a button, you want to set the attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--------------Mind reading mode on---------------------

You have;

```
<input id='input1' type='text'>
<input id='input2' type='text'>
<input id='input3' type='text'>
<button>Copy data</button>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var string = "test?input1="+$('#input1').val()+"&input2="+$('#input2').val();
        $('#input3').data('link', string);
    });
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/bGTQJ/